# how to put a date in jdbc namedparameter

Tags: java, jdbctemplate, named-parameters

I have the following code:

```
conditions.add("mydate = str_to_date('"+date_from_user+"', '%Y-%m-%d')");
```

the above works fine but since I am taking input from the user and shoving it in my query I'm risking the security of the query. So I wanted to use named template so I changed the code to:

```
conditions.add("mydate = str_to_date(':mydate', '%Y-%m-%d')");
namedParams.put("mydate", date_from_user);
```

However, the above code doesn't work and produces the following error message:

```
<SQLWarning ignored: SQL state 'HY000', error code '1411', message [Incorrect datetime value: ':mydate' for function str_to_date]>
```

so it seems that namedparameter isn't picking up the value..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the quotes in `':mydate'` and change it as below,

```
conditions.add("mydate = str_to_date(:mydate, '%Y-%m-%d')");
namedParams.put("mydate", date_from_user);
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your DB server date format. Then give input in same format. create your date object in the same Object or pass string in same format.